# what nuget packages for jquery autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, nuget, nuget-package, jquery-widgets

I am just learning both jquery and the nuget package manager.  I want to use the autocomplete widget.  I ran "Install-Package jquery".  Then I think it was “Install-Package jquery.ui.combined”.  If I try to run jQuery.UI.Widgets.Autocomplete” it won't work.  I tried installing core as it looked like a dependency and that wouldn't work either.

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.UI.Widgets.Autocomplete
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery.UI.Core (= 1.8.9)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery (≥ 1.4.4 && < 1.6)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery.UI.Core.Widget (= 1.8.9)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery.UI.Core.Position (= 1.8.9)'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.4.4'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery.UI.Core 1.8.9'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery.UI.Core.Widget 1.8.9'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery.UI.Core.Position 1.8.9'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery.UI.Widgets.Autocomplete 1.8.9'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'jQuery'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  jQuery.UI.Widgets.Autocomplete
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

When I type "get-package" I see the following

```
jQuery                         1.6.2                
jQuery.UI.Combined             1.8.14               
jQuery.vsdoc                   1.6                  
Newtonsoft.Json                4.0.2
```

Is the autocomplete looking for an older version?  Can someone guide me on how to either keep installing packages in order to get this to work or how to uninstall them and install the proper ones in the proper order?

Answer (score 3):

The version of jQuery you have installed (1.6.2) is too recent a version for jQuery.UI.Core (1.8.9).

- jQuery.UI.Widgets.Autocomplete 1.8.9 requires jQuery.UI.Core v1.8.9
- jQuery.UI.Core 1.8.9 requires a version of jQuery from 1.4.4 but below 1.6

I would first uninstall all the jQuery packages and then install jQuery.UI.Widgets.Autocomplete. NuGet will then install a compatible version of jQuery for you. Then you can install jQuery.UI.Combined.